# How to Update the .config file using Azure DevOps "Update config" Task

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to Update the `Web.config` file using Azure DevOps Release Pipeline.
I am using [Update Config][1] Task from MarketPlace.
[1]: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=digitalmedia34.updateconfig

Here Is the `Web.config` File

```
<!-- Some Contents -->
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="Setting1" value="local setting"/>
    <add key="CommonSetting" value="local common setting"/>
  </appSettings>
  
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDB"
         connectionString="Data Source=LocalSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyReleaseDB;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx" />
  </connectionStrings>
  
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework1="4.7.2"/>
  </system.web>
  
</configuration>
```

I am able to change the value of some configuration by adding variables like [Variables]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uq85Y.png

My Question is how can I change the values of Nested Property. For Example if I want to change the `targetFramework` in

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework1="4.7.2"/>
  </system.web>
```

Please let me know how can I update these values

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> How to Update the .config file using Azure DevOps "Update config" Task

You could use the task [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to update the key's values,

the format of variable in `.config` file is `#{TestVersion}#`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="Setting1" value="local setting"/>
    <add key="CommonSetting" value="local common setting"/>
  </appSettings>
  
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDB"
         connectionString="Data Source=LocalSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyReleaseDB;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx" />
  </connectionStrings>
  
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="#{TestVersion}#"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework1="#{TestVersion}#"/>
  </system.web>
  
</configuration>
```

Use Replace Tokens task to update the key's values:

[image]

And define the key's values on the Variables.